# Date reflects incorrectly due to Time Zone setting on Sharepoint

Tags: vba, datetime, sharepoint-2007, ms-access-2010

We're using an Access application that stores and retrieves information from SharePoint, and the times and dates get viewed through the 'filter' of the Time Zone settings on SharePoint.

This has started to cause a problem when just trying to enter a date with no time. People marked as CST will see 7/1/2014 0:00, but those in PST will see 6/30/2014 22:00. Calculations that organise metrics by date would then show the same entry in June for PST users and July for CST.

Is there a way to adjust for this? I don't WANT to be capturing a time in this field, but since it's a Date/Time field on SharePoint, it's attaching a time anyway. Would changing the field in question to 'String' work or would that cause more problems than a more adaptive solution?

(I've read links that popped up in 'Questions that may already have your answer', conducted other searches on and off Stack.)

Comment: I've not seen the Sharepoint version of this problem, but I have dealt with Oracle date-time info in Access. One trick is to use Format(<date-time>,"mm/dd/yyyy"). This wills strip the time portion before you do the compare. I've also cheated and used Int(<date-time>). The date portion is integer.

Comment: The 'format method' is what I'm currently using, and if I understand correctly, using your INT Idea would likely run into the same issues both ways. The CST person writing the value would save the date as 41821, but it'd show as 41820(.92) on the PST client.

I appreciate the reply, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of testing after all my Users went home except for one, I found that just changing the type on SharePoint for the fields in question from 'Date/Time' to 'Text (Single Line)' worked perfectly.  My Tester had no issues with the VB used to store information and bringing up the raw tables showed the 'proper' date stamps after a restart of the client database.

It seems a little too good to be true, but it appears to be a victory!  I'll definitely come back here with an update if anything blows up.